# How to use the What If Tool (WIT) provided by google in my Keras Model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboardx

I use the Tensorboard callback and I am able to access all the graphs provided but how to use the What If Tool in the Tensorboard environment. I went through the official Google post but could not figure out much. Could someone please outline the different steps to be followed from a normal Tensorboard callback?

Comment: Even I had searched for it, but no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use WIT for a keras model, check out the information on using WIT inside of jupyter or colab notebooks, where you can write a wrapper for your keras model to use it with WIT directly in the notebook.

documentation: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/tree/master/tensorboard/plugins/interactive_inference#notebook-mode-details

a colab example of wrapping a Keras model to use with WIT:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/pair-code/what-if-tool/blob/master/WIT_Toxicity_Text_Model_Comparison.ipynb

Comment: this look really helpful. Could you elaborate a little bit more, what steps generally need to be taken to make WIT work with keras models? Do the steps vary dependent on the data and model architecture? Would it be an alternative to convert the keras model to tensorflow? (https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow)

Comment: Assuming your Keras model is classification or regression (the two model types supported by WIT), you can use it with WIT inside of notebook without converting it to a TF model. As shown in the notebook in the above answer, the first step is to convert the data you want to run through the model to tf.Example proto format, as that is what WIT expects. Then write a custom python function that can take in a list of those protos and run inference on your Keras model (it should convert those protos back to whatever format your model needs and call predict on the model).

Comment: Here is another example colab notebook showing using WIT on a Keras model: https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/PAIR-code/what-if-tool/blob/master/WIT_Smile_Detector.ipynb#scrollTo=E5fYynA9ZpPJ